# The hash of plugin package is not correct

Tags: notepad++

I have tried to install some packages in npp on my new computer (win10) but I've got this message:

[image: npp error]
It is for every package which I have tried to install. 
Do you know what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You get the latest version in the link given below:

https://github.com/pnedev/compare-plugin/releases/tag/v2.0.0

Just go to the page and download the compatible version by clicking on the Asset (Desired for your system). Once the ZIP is downloaded , open the plugins folder(This you get in the tool bar-> Plugins-> Open Plugin Folder, in Notepad++). Create a folder named,ComparePlugin. Paste the extracted file, ComparePlugin.dll in this folder.

Then just restart Notepad++ and you can see the plugin in the list.
Similarly, you can do for all the Plugins you need.
Hope the answer helps.